# watchman, how to wait until file has copied before subscribe event emits

Tags: node.js, watchman

I am watching a directory and subscribed to any files that are added. When I get a subscribe event, I move that file to another directory where I do some stuff.

Issue: When I copy files into that directory, I sometimes get this error in finder:

```
The operation can’t be completed because one or more required items can’t be found. (Error code -43)
```

Is watchman not waiting for the file to completely copy over before it triggers the subscribe event? I used to use a npm module called 'chokidar' and they had an option that would wait until the file closes before they emit any change/add/delete events. Does fb-watchman have something similar?

thank you

Comment: Did you find an answer to this issue @Jerry?

Comment: No, i had to make a work around where I polled the file's file size and modified time. Not the best solution